# MAMP PRO PHP 5.3.5, Intl required by symfony2

Tags: php, apache, mamp, symfony, intl

Symfony2 is setup apart from one thing and that is "intl"

I found instructions to get this working for the latest mamp pro but step 0 doesn't make sense to me, I ignored it and tried to carry on with setup but everything works until I get to "make install" , I get errors at that part.

I am running snow leopard.

http://szemian.wordpress.com/2011/03/21/compiling-intl-extension-for-mamp/#comments

after I've typed make and it's done what it has to do I get this message at the end:

```
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-local'.
make[0]: Making `all' in `test'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all-local'.
```

and after I choose make install I get this message:

```
make[0]: Making `install' in `stubdata'
/bin/sh ../mkinstalldirs /usr/local/lib
/usr/bin/install -c libicudata.46.1.dylib /usr/local/lib
install: /usr/local/lib/libicudata.46.1.dylib: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-library] Error 71
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 2
```

Can anyone advise me?

Comment: What do yo mean by "doesn't make sense to me"? Why not post the errors you're getting?

Comment: It says "Instruct the compiler to compile in both 32 and 64 bit"

Comment: I've updated my original message to make this my issue clearer

Comment: Symfony2 does not strictly require intl. There are stub implementations of all of the used classes. So unless you need advanced intl features, you should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On UNIX systems, you're supposed to be administrator to install something. Hence you should launch `make install` as root (use `sudo`, I'm not sure whether root exists in Mac OS).

Regarding the step 0, why exactly are you reluctant to "Instruct the compiler to compile in both 32 and 64 bit" architectures?

Comment: Done the install using sudo. All seems fine but I'm still getting that message in symfony2 asking for the intl. I've added the full path to the extension to my php5.3 file.

Comment: @Psychonetics: is this extension listed in the display of `phpinfo()` ?

Comment: @Did you restart your apache server? If yes, did you get any message in your apache logs

Comment: [31-May-2011 00:09:14] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so' - dlopen(/Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so, 9): no suitable image found.  Did find:
 /Applications/MAMP/bin/php5.3/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/intl.so: mach-o, but wrong architecture in Unknown on line 0

Comment: @Psychonetics : you seem to have compiled intl only in one architecture, so I'm asking you, *again*, why exactly are you reluctant to "Instruct the compiler to compile in both 32 and 64 bit" architectures?